# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un SELECT dependiendo de los baneos de los usuarios? (PHP)

Tags: php

Cree un top de los staffs con más baneos, muestra la cantidad de baneos de cada usuario staff y todo lo demás pero no lo muestro en orden a los baneos que tenga cada usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No consigo como ordenarlos del que tenga más baneos al que menos tenga (ej: 100,99,98, etc..), lo demás lo hice con lo que sabía (y creo que está mal) y llevo horas intentando como hacerlo.

```
$cuentas = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank >= 8 LIMIT 5");
if($cuentas->num_rows == 0){
    echo '<div class="alert red">No hay usuarios con rango aún...</div>';
}
else{
    $nmms_puesto = 1;
    $oddEven = "odd";
    while($staff_bans = $cuentas->fetch_assoc()){
        if($oddEven != "even"){
            $oddEven = "even";
        }
        else{
            $oddEven = "odd";
        }

        //parámetros bien rikos
        $user_id = $staff_bans['id'];
        $user_look = $staff_bans['look'];
        $user_name = $staff_bans['username'];
        $user_conection = date('d-m-Y', $staff_bans['last_online']);
        $user_online = $staff_bans['online'];
        if($user_online == '0'){
            $user_online_ = "filter: grayscale(1);opacity: 0.5";
        }
        else{
            $user_online_ = null;
        }

        // shekamos aca bien shidoriz los baneos
        $shekar_bans = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE user_staff_id = '".$user_id."'");
        $numero_bans = $shekar_bans->num_rows;

        // wueno aka tu zabes we alv asdjalsd
        switch($nmms_puesto){
            //primera posicion
            case 1: $badge = "gold"; 
            break;
            //segunda posicion
            case 2: $badge = "silver"; 
            break;
            //tercera posicion
            case 3: $badge = "bronze"; 
            break;
            //demas posiciones
            default: $badge = "up";
            break;
        }
        if($shekar_bans->num_rows == 0){
            echo 'No hay baneos disponibles, vuelve más tarde...<br>';
        }
        else{
        echo '
        <div class="box-select-content '.$oddEven.'">
            <div style="float:left;margin-top:-10px;height:55px;'.$user_online_.'">
            <img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='.$user_look.'$user&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif">
            </div>
            <span><b><a href="/user/'.$user_name.'" target="_blank">'.$user_name.'</a> - (ID: '.$user_id.')</b></span><br>
            <span><b>Cantidad de baneos:</b> '.$numero_bans.'</span><br>
            <span><b>Última conexión:</b> '.$user_conection.'</span>
            <img src="../images/web-gallery/v2/images/halloffame/'.$badge.'.png" style="float:right;margin: -15px 5px;">
        </div>
        ';
        $nmms_puesto++;
        }
    }
}
```

Espero una solución, soy novato en php, perdonen si está desordenado o mal el código. Gracias por leer.

Comment: Quieres mostrar en orden del usuario que mas baneos tiene al que menos? o que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Sí, quiero hacer eso. Primero los que tengan más  al que tenga menos.

Comment: como se llama la columna que tiene registrados el número de baneos?

Comment: además que guarda o para que sirve la columna rank?

Comment: @Aprendiz, La tabla que registra los baneos es 'bans', en el código que mostré sale todas las consultas que estoy utilizando.

Comment: La columna rank es sólo precaución, es decir, solo saldrán en el top los que tengan rango igual o mayor a 8.

Comment: si pero la columna donde se guarda el número de baneos que hja hecho cada usuario como se llama¿

Comment: La columna para la tabla 'bans' es 'user_staff_id', de ahí solo cuenta los baneos de los staffs.

Comment: No se guarda la cantidad en la base de datos o columna, utilicé num_rows para contar las columnas o tablas dentro de la tabla 'bans' dependiendo del id del staff 'user_staff_id'. @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

Deberás agregar a tu consulta el uso de `ORDER BY` y de `DESC` para que muestre del usuario con mayor número de baneos al que menos baneos a realizado:

**Opción 1**

```
 $shekar_bans = $db->query("SELECT columna1, columna2,  COUNT(user_staff_id) AS 
                                   total 
                            FROM bans 
                            WHERE user_staff_id = '".$user_id."'
                            GROUP BY columna1, columna2
                            ORDER BY total DESC");
```

Yo haría uso de la función de agregación `COUNT()` (pues no me parece correcto el modo en que lo haces), pasandole como argumento el nombre de la columna `user_staff_id` pues esta junto con la condición del `WHERE` me ayuda a filtrar y contar solo aquellos baneos de un usuario determinado por el id que pasemos en la variable `$user_id`.

Le indicamos que columnas esperamos que nos retorne, como no las conozco entonces le puse `columna1` y `columna2` mismas que después debo usar en la sentencia de `GROUP BY`.

Al final ordeno los resultados por el número de baneos que se almacenan en la variable temporal llamada `total`.

Al usar al final `ORDER BY DESC` junto con la columna `total` lo que le indico es que ordene los números de baneos del mayor al menor

Comment: Borro la consulta que tenía y coloco esta, o la pongo aparte?

Comment: en lugar de, no borres la tuya comémtala, coloca la mia y haz pruebas

Comment: Tengo problemas **Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string**. ¿Podrías ayudarme mediante teamviewer o anydesk?, es que lo necesito para hoy.

Comment: No funciona, me podrías ayudar en privado?